# Function which creates objects that have global name

Tags: lua

I had this code which simply displays a picture I need in my game.

```
DeckOfPlayingCards = display.newImageRect("Graphics/ImproveMenu/Wealth/Luxury/Buy/DeckOfPlayingCards.png", 96*6, 96)
DeckOfPlayingCards.x = centerX
DeckOfPlayingCards.y = -90
DeckOfPlayingCards.name = "DeckOfPlayingCards"
```

Now, since I have a lot of these pictures planned to be in my game menu, I don't want to copy-paste that code all over. I wanted to make a simple function that would do it for me. This is what I tried, but failed and don't know why.

```
function DisplayObject(object, x, y, name)
        object = display.newImageRect("Graphics/ImproveMenu/Wealth/Luxury/Buy/" ..name..".png", 96*6, 96)
        object.x = x
        object.y = y
        object.name = name

        scrollView:insert(object)
end

DisplayObject(DeckOfPlayingCards, centerX, -90, "DeckOfPlayingCards")
```

This function can successfully show the picture, but whenever I try to do something with it (make it a button), it says the value is nil. After doing the function, I tried to do print the name like so:

```
function DisplayObject(object, x, y, name)
        object = display.newImageRect("Graphics/ImproveMenu/Wealth/Luxury/Buy/" ..name..".png", 96*6, 96)
        object.x = x
        object.y = y
        object.name = name

        scrollView:insert(object)
end

DisplayObject(DeckOfPlayingCards, centerX, -90, "DeckOfPlayingCards")

print(DeckOfPlayingCards.name)
```

It crashes and says that the value is nil.

Now, how can I exactly make my object with function that will be as I tried to write it like the first code? I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: My answer is sadly more of a guess. I have no idea why your code isn't working, but hopefully a return should work anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve it.
http://prntscr.com/ab22dp

Comment: It's some application specific thing then, what program/engine are you using?

Comment: I am using Corona SDK and writing my game in Sublime Text 2. Still fairly new to all this, I am kinda sad I can't get this to work. Searched everywhere, can't find answer.

Comment: I thought you predefined that... My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DisplayObject(DeckOfPlayingCards, centerX, -90, "DeckOfPlayingCards")
```

I think you expect this to act as passing the *name* `DeckOfPlayingCards` to `DisplayObject`, but it's just passing `nil` because it's an undefined variable.

One option is to simply create the object in `DisplayObject`, return it, then assign it to `DeckOfPlayingCards`:

```
function DisplayObject(x, y, name)
   local object = display.newImageRect(
       "Graphics/ImproveMenu/Wealth/Luxury/Buy/" ..name..".png",
       96*6, 96)
   object.x = x
   object.y = y
   object.name = name

   scrollView:insert(object)
   return object
end

DeckOfPlayingCards = DisplayObject(centerX, -90, "DeckOfPlayingCards")

print(DeckOfPlayingCards.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what is wrong. You cannot index a nil value.
Therefor DeckOfPlayingCards must be nil.

Where do you initialize DeckOfPlayingCards? I understand that the first block of code is not part of your current script as you moved it into the new function DisplayObject.

Assuming that DeckOfPlayingCards is nil when you call DisplayObject(object, x, y, name) object is also nil within your function.
As lua only creates a local copy of the function parameters you set the local variable object to the return value of display.newImageRect...

This does not change the value of DeckOfPlayingCards!!! It is still nil.

What you do is the same as:

```
function DisplayObject(x, y, name)        
  local object = display.newImageRect("Graphics/ImproveMenu/Wealth/Luxury/Buy/" ..name..".png", 96*6, 96)
        object.x = x
        object.y = y
        object.name = name

        scrollView:insert(object)
end
```

Return object and store it in DeckOfPlayingCards to solve your problem.

Comment: Guy above solved it for me. As he and you said, I tried to pass a nil value into a function.Forgive me, I am still new to all this, trying to catch up. However, thank you for your contribution!

Comment: True! Thank you again!